Does anycharts support stack labels in stacked charts?
Does anycharts support stack labels like highcahrts?
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/column-stacked
Or is there any way to add these stack labels?
I have tried using the annotatios().label it works fine for stacked column charts but it does not work for stacked bar charts.

This works fine for column chart: https://playground.anychart.com/KBKhP86c/2
This one does not work correctly.: https://playground.anychart.com/KBKhP86c/3

I would prefer if there was a option to just enable the stackedLabels like in hightcharts but from the documentations anycharts does not support this.

It is possible to display the stack labels with AnyChart.
Here’s how you can achieve this:

Enable labels for chart

chart.labels().enabled(true)


Turn off labels for first two series

series1.labels(false)
series2.labels(false)


Format the last series lables

series3.labels().format("{%CategoryYSum}")

Explore an updated Playground Demo: example of displaying the stacked labels with AnyChart.
Feel free to explore a Documentation Page about formatting functions.

Well the only problem with this is that all my charts are alredy using the labels(enabled).position('center'), so i can't use the last label to use the stacked format. https://playground.anychart.com/2xoWqgPf/2
